# Powerapp: Submit form if column value is true

Tags: form-submit, powerapps

I created a powerapp from a SharePoint list and want to have a conditional rule as follows: If card value = "Inquiry call" then submit form without continuing through the rest of the form. If not, continue.  I haven't been able to find anything about doing this. I started to create the rule below but I cannot find rules on the action.

Type_x0020_of_x0020_Referral_DataCard2.Update = Inquiry Call - No Referral

Please advise. Thank you!

[Form[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KSpv.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific about "submit without continuing through he rest of the form" (a picture would help)? Is the referral card in the middle of the form, and *you're assuming that the user will fill the form in order* (you shouldn't assume this)? If the user selects "Inquiry call" by mistake, do you want to submit the form anyway?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this.  You're correct, I should not assume they will fill this out in order.  I'm trying to develop a tracking mechanism to report/trend off of.  In the event that a call is an Inquiry, there is no additional action later in the form so I'd like to Submit if inquiry is selected. And yes, it is in the middle of the form.

Comment: You can set a rule that will *disable* (or hide) the cards after the referral update, if its value is "Inquiry call". This way the user will have a visual indication that they don't need to continue filling the form, but if they want to change it they can still do that.